# Didn't return anything in FileStream CopyToAsync

Tags: .net, blazor, filestream, webassembly

While upload the more than 100MB file and reading stream CopyToAsync method didn't returns anything in Blazor WASM. Since it is working fine Blazor server. I tried with below code. Please suggest any solution for that.

```
private async Task LoadFiles(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var file in e.GetMultipleFiles(maxAllowedFiles))
    {
        try
        {
           string tmpfile = Path.GetTempFileName();
           await using FileStream fs = new(tmpfile, FileMode.Append);
           await file.OpenReadStream((int)file.Size).CopyToAsync(fs);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What happens if there is an exception?

Comment: WebAssembly runs in the browser. You don't have access to files in the server. Are you sure you are opening the file? My bet is that this is where exception is thrown.